# why $b$ does not belong to $A?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Show that every non-zero prime ideal of a principal ideal domain is
maximal.

I found the answer [here](https://people.math.sc.edu/sumner/math5472006/ProblemSets/problems8A.pdf) Page no $:1$

> Here is an outline of  answer

> Solution: Suppose that A is a prime ideal of the principal ideal domain $D$. Then
> $A = < a >$ for some $a \neq 0$ in $D$. Suppose that $A$ is not maximal. Then there is some
> proper ideal $B$ such that $A$ is properly contained in $B$. Say, $B = <b>$.
> But then $a$ belongs to $B$ and so $a = bd$ for some $d$ in $D$. But then $bd$ belongs to $A$ and
> so **since $b$ does not belong to $A$**, it must be that $d$ belongs to $A.$ However this means
> that $d = ar$ for some $r$ in $D$. Hence, $a = bar$ and so $a(1– br) = 0$. Thus, $br = 1$ and so
> $b$ is a unit. But then this means that $B = R$

My confusion :Im  not getting why $b$ does not belong to $A?$

My thinking : Here  $A$ is properly contained in $B$ that means $b\in A$  and  $B=(b) \subset  A$

Comment: We are assuming $B=\langle b \rangle \supset \langle a \rangle=A$ which immediately implies $b\not \in A$, as otherwise $\langle b \rangle \subseteq A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $b\in A$, then $B=(b)\subset A$, so $B=A$, which is impossible by the assumption that $A$ is properly contained in $B$.